# A href link does not work-When I click the link snimka1.html it does not work,may be to many div tags?-

Tags: html, image, hyperlink, href

When I click the link snimka1.html it does not work,may be to many div tags?

snimka1 is located on the server in the same /main/ directory as index.html.

I removed the tag `<div class="panel-thumbnail">` and the link works, but the images are in a tab and they changed their places and are not correctly displayed

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-thumbnail">
          <a href="snimka1.html" target="_blank">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="img-responsive psp-center" alt="business">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p ALIGN="center">Kлеопатра 2,4X 3,2 см </p>
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is `snimka1.html` file located?

Comment: snimka1 is located on the server in the same /main/ directory as index.html. Whem i remove this tag <div class="panel-thumbnail">, the link works?

Comment: Maybe some JavaScript binding kicks in for class `panel-thumbnail` which suppresses the link functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number of div tags doesn't matter.
Make sure your 'snimka1.html' file is in the same folder of your index.html.

If it is in another folder you should include that folder name also. like 'foldername/snimka1.html'.

Refer this link once - https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

Answer (score 1):

[The comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69952816/a-href-link-does-not-work-when-i-click-the-link-snimka1-html-it-does-not-work-ma/69954337#comment123656138_69952816) that [f_puras](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1606632/f-puras) posted:

> Maybe some JavaScript binding kicks in for class `panel-thumbnail` which suppresses the link functionality.

was right. I removed `class="panel-thumbnail"` from the `<div>` tag and the link works!

Comment: No - there is no answer to accept. f_puras posted a comment, not an answer. I've edited this answer to make that clearer.